# What information about a user can I access when I get him/her to login into my appl. through twitter

Tags: twitter, authentication, twitter-oauth

I want to provide a "Login with twitter" functionality for my web application.When the user logs in, I want to request him to share specific information about his profile and tweets as I want to read that information and build some recommendations based on that. However, I do not know what all information can be had from this twitter for that user. Can you please point me to some code/docs that help me do this.

Thanks
kabir

Comment: What have you found so far from reading the docs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

// Get consumer key and consumer secret from config file
// retrieve access token stored in database

require_once('twitteroauth.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET );

$response = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

// This returns an object with the following info (user account info)
// [https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials][1]

$response2 = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');

// This returns an object with the following info (user timeline tweets) 
//https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

?>
```